# SQLAlchemy hybrid property on if else block

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask-SQLAlchemy model that have `delivery_at` and `read_at` DateType fields.

```
class Foo(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    delivered_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    read_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Based on data fields I would like to have calculated `status` using hybrid property.
And what I have now looks like:

```
    @hybrid_property
    def status(self):
        value = ('Opened', 'Received', 'Undelivered')

        if self.delivered_at and self.read_at:
            return value[0]
        elif self.delivered_at and not self.read_at:
            return value[1]
        else:
            return value[2]

@status.expression
    def status(cls):
        from sqlalchemy import text
        value = ('Opened', 'Received', 'Undelivered')
        return case(
            [(text('(foo.delivered_at is not null) and (foo.read_at is not null)'), value[0]),
             (text('(foo.delivered_at is not null) and (foo.read_at is null)'), value[1])], else_=value[2]
        )
```

I can do `filter_by`, but group by throws me an error:

```
>>> res = Foo.query.filter_by(status='Opened').all()
>>> res
[<Foo 1>]

res = db.session.query(Foo.status, func.count(Foo.status)).group_by(Foo.status).all()
```

Traceback for group_by:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3186, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3342, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3367, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1253, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1473, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/foo/.virtualenvs/bar/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 580, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) missing FROM-clause entry for table "foo"
LINE 1: SELECT CASE WHEN (foo.delivered_at is not null) ...
```

Any advice?

Comment: Should `and_(OwnersMessages.delivered_at != None, OwnersMessages.read_at)` be `and_(OwnersMessages.delivered_at != None, OwnersMessages.read_at == None)`? If `filter_by` does not work, try `filter` instead. And you have not shown any code using group by. And how does it not work? Is there an error? Wrong results?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I added a group by query to the question. Example error for group by query is: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) missing FROM-clause entry for table "foo"
LINE 1: SELECT CASE WHEN (foo.delivered_at is not null)

Comment: Please add the error in the question as well, with traceback.

Comment: I managed to figure out filter_by, the only thing is group_by now.

Comment: Given your new version of the hybrid expression's SQL side, it should be somewhat obvious why it cannot pick up the required FROM item automatically: you've rewritten it to use `text()` clauses instead of the model class and SQLA expression language. That's also error prone in the face of using aliases etc.